# Проблема с REST

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, phalcon

Отправляю через Advanced Rest Client на Phalcon

```
$app->put('/feedback/{id:[0-9]+}', function ($id) use ($app) {

   $test = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();
    file_put_contents('test2.txt',json_encode($test),FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Всё нормально пишется-читается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробую отправлять из Angularjs

```
 this.resource = $resource(url, {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET', params: {quest_id: '@quest_id'}, isArray: true},
                delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {}, isObject: true},
                save: {method: 'POST'},
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    params: {quest_id: '@quest_id',feedback:'korolariya'}
                }
            });
```

$scope.feedback.resource.update({"feedback":"korolariya","user_id":"24","quest_id":"5"});

Запрос уходит но в json ничего нет, а в POST и не попадёт потому что PUT

Answer (score 2):

В общем ткнул наугад:

```
update: {
    method: 'PUT',
    transformRequest: function(data, headers){
        console.log(headers);
        headers = angular.extend({}, headers, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(angular.toJson(data));
        return angular.toJson(data); // this will go in the body request
    },
    params: {quest_id: '@quest_id'}
}
```

оставлю если вдруг у кого похожая проблема будет, ну или у меня повториться